# How can a module be imported in a Python module only after a function in the module is run?

Tags: python, module, python-import, dependency-management

I want a Python module I'm writing to import a dependency module only if a function in my module is run. This is because the dependency module is very complex (i.e. it sets server programs running etc.) and is available only on some systems on which my module is to be used. I imagine using my module in a way like this:

```
import mymodule
mymodule.simple_function() # just a simple function to be used on any system

mymodule.import_complex_dependencies()
mymodule.function_that_uses_functionality_of_the_complex_dependency_module()
```

Assuming that I am not going to split my module into two and that I am not going to make a submodule, what would be some way to do this?

Comment: Why don't you accept one of the answers ?

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D I'm grateful for the solutions proposed so far, and these solutions are useful to some people, but they are not, as far as I can see, a solution for me. I need to avoid importing the complex module multiple times.

Comment: If the module is imported once then it is never reimported - what don't you understand ? Put a print in your module, follow @user2357112 solution and see the print only once no matter how many method invocations

Answer (score 4):

If only some particular function needs that module, have only that particular function import the module:

```
def func_with_dependencies():
    import dependency
    ...
```

Comment: The OP says that some functions are required on all the modules.

Comment: @VMAtm: What the heck are you talking about?

Comment: OP said that he need some simple functions from `mymodule` for all systems, and some complicated ones for the selected ones. Just trying to clarify your solution, why so mean?

Comment: @VMAtm: `import dependency` goes in the specific functions from `mymodule` that need the complex dependency. We're conditionally importing the dependency, not conditionally importing `mymodule`.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks muchly for your suggestion, which would normally be a reasonable one. Unfortunately, the complexity of this dependency module is such that I can't really be importing it multiple times (and there are multiple functions in my module that use it). Could it be imported such that it exists outside of the scope of just a function?

Comment: @BlandCorporation: `import`ing something repeatedly doesn't initialize it repeatedly. The module is only loaded once, and further imports simply retrieve the existing module object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
complex_stuff = None

def load_complex_stuff():
    global complex_stuff
    if complex_stuff is None:
        import complex_stuff


def func_using_it():
    load_complex_stuff()
    ... more ...


def func_using_it_2():
    load_complex_stuff()
    ... more ...
```

This way the complex stuff only gets loaded once.

Comment: Unless I am missing something there is no need for that logic (`load_complex_stuff()`) as import is a noop if the module is already imported

Comment: @Claudiu Thanks for your suggestion. I need to avoid importing this complex module multiple times.